# Who was the first to prove the Monotone Class Lemma?

Tags: real-analysis, math-history

Who was the first one to prove the [Monotone Class Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem) in history? I learned that it is sort of equivalent to the [$\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system#Dynkin.27s_.CF.80-.CE.BB_theorem) in probability theory. Which theorem appeared first in history? I saw some textbook calls "Halmos's monotone class lemma". But I am not able to find the source of his paper.

Comment: Elstrodt writes that the earliest proof of general versions of this (and a related) theorem he's aware of is by Sierpiński.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I'm not able to find Elstrodt's words (do you have a reference?).

Comment: But I do find something similar by searching "Sierpinski" and the Monotone Class Theorem in Google.

Comment: Jürgen Elstrodt, _Maß- und Integrationstheorie_, Springer Verlag 1996, Chapter I, §6. It's at the bottom of page 25 (in the first edition at least), "Es gibt in der Literatur eine ganze Reihe von Varianten der Sätze 6.2 und 6.8. Die älteste dem Verfasser bekannte allgemeine Version wurde 1927 von W. Sierpiński ([1], S. 640-642) angegeben, der einen sehr klaren Beweis unter Benutzung des Prinzips der guten Mengen führt."

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Daniel Fischer's answer, with the help of Google Translate (and some minor editing): According to Elstrodt,

> There are a number of variants of Theorems 6.2 [the Monotone Class
> Theorem] and 6.7 in the literature. The oldest general version known
> to the author was given in 1927 by Wacław SIERPINSKI (*Oeuvres
> choisis, Tome II*. Warszawa: PWN-Editions Scientifiques de Pologne
> 1975, pp. 640-642), who gives a very clear proof using the principle
> of good sets. In this way he avoids the transfinite induction most
> often used in older works. SIERPINSKI even proves a necessary and
> sufficient criterion that corresponds to our Problem 6.2. His result
> was included in the textbook literature by Hans HAHN, *Reelle
> Funktionen. Erster Teil: Punktfunktionen.* Leipzig: Akademische
> Verlagsges. 1932, pp. 262, 33.2.61. A slightly different version of
> the statement can be found in Stanisław SAKS *Theory of the integral.*
> Second ed. Warszawa 1937. Nachdrucke: New York: Hafner Publ. Comp.;
> New York: Dover Publications 1964, p. 85, (9.7).

NOTE: Of these references, Saks is the only one cited by Halmos in his *Measure Theory* textbook.